# gstreamer 1.0 error control and sending eos

Tags: python, gstreamer

Okey regarding gstreamer 1.0 documentation and porting guide I didn't found anything about events.I tried to set an eos signal in my pipeline so that mp4mux can finalize stream like this:

```
self.pipe.send_event(Gst.event_new_eos())
```

but got error:

```
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gst' object has no attribute 'event_new_eos'
```

And I tought I got spelling or something wrong I googled and found few examples in 0.10 and nothing on 1.0 but the problem is that I didn't found anything about `send_event` or `Gst.event_new_eos()` in porting guide.I would be grateful if somebody could tell me what am I missing here?

Regarding gstreamer and tee element Iam curious about handling different branches for example if I have this pipeline :

```
  gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! tee name=spliter  spliter. ! queue ! udpsink  spliter. ! queue ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=something.mp4
```

How could I handle problems like lost connection or not enough hard disk without pipeline going down when something like that happens?

Answer (score 10):

Sending EOS event in gstreamer0.10:

```
  self.pipeline.send_event(gst.event_new_eos())
```

Sending EOS even in gstreamer1.0:

```
self.pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
```

PS: I've stumbled against same issue and I also wasn't able find documentation regarding events in gstreamer 1.0 but was I able to figure it out myself. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For those who still did not find any python+gstreamer api documentation: http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gst-1.0